# Nested string interpolation in JavaScript

Tags: angular, angular-routing, browser-security

While trying to generate a **URL** dynamically I ended up nesting interpolation like below:

```js
`api/topics/${topicId}/assessments${assessmentId ? `/${assessmentId}` : ''}`;
```

This worked correctly, but my worry is if this brings with it any security **vulnerabilities** in an Angular built application.

Comment: This is basically using the template literal. Please save this to a local variable and pass that variable for service call.

Comment: @JijoCleetus can nesting template literal be exploited?

Comment: Not a big issue, since the template literals will be pre rendered in the view.